# Python - why use "self" in a class?

Tags: python, oop

How do these 2 classes differ?

```
class A():
    x=3

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=3
```

Is there any significant difference?

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @hop: Interesting assertion, but you haven't provided any example or evidence that it's not a duplicate.  Why do you say that?

Comment: @S.Lott - Huh?  The other question is asking why we need to explicitly pass self.  This one is asking about the difference because class and instance variables.

Comment: @S.Lott That isn't the same question. I even looked at that one before asking it.

Comment: @S.Lott: 68282 is a useless question about why you have to explicitly put self as the first argument to methods; this question asks about the difference between class and instance members. S.Lott, I really like your contributions to SO, but this time you are wrong.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`A.x` is a *class variable*.
`B`'s `self.x` is an *instance variable*.

i.e. `A`'s `x` is shared between instances.

It would be easier to demonstrate the difference with something that can be modified like a list:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:
    x = []
    def add(self):
        self.x.append(1)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
    def add(self):
        self.x.append(1)

x = A()
y = A()
x.add()
y.add()
print("A's x:", x.x)

x = B()
y = B()
x.add()
y.add()
print("B's x:", x.x)
```

Output

```
A's x: [1, 1]
B's x: [1]
```

Comment: Maybe also post the output of your script, then one can see the difference without copying and running it oneself...

Comment: Is python's self equivalent to Java's this then? Excuse the noobishness please

Comment: @Jean - Yes-ish - self has to be just the conventional name given to the first parameter of instance methods - and python explicitly passes the current instance of instance methods as the first argument to instance methods. But it does the same job as Java's this

Comment: @Jean Azzopardi: self is almost like Java (and c++) this.  Self is simply required; this is sometimes reasoned out by the Java compiler (other times it's required.)

Comment: @Douglas Leeder - no problem.

Comment: Just a quick note: You can reassign the variable to decouple it from the class variable.  I.e. change add() to do "self.x=self.x + [1]".

Answer (score 61):

Just as a side note: `self` is actually just a randomly chosen word, that everyone uses, but you could also use `this`, `foo`, or `myself` or anything else you want, it's just the first parameter of every non static method for a class. This means that the word `self` is not a language construct but just a name:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(s):
...        s.bla = 2
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.bla
2
```

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment

Answer (score 25):

A.x is a class variable, and will be shared across all instances of A, unless specifically overridden within an instance.
B.x is an instance variable, and each instance of B has its own version of it.

I hope the following Python example can clarify:

```
    >>> class Foo():
    ...     i = 3
    ...     def bar(self):
    ...             print 'Foo.i is', Foo.i
    ...             print 'self.i is', self.i
    ... 
    >>> f = Foo() # Create an instance of the Foo class
    >>> f.bar()
    Foo.i is 3
    self.i is 3
    >>> Foo.i = 5 # Change the global value of Foo.i over all instances
    >>> f.bar()
    Foo.i is 5
    self.i is 5
    >>> f.i = 3 # Override this instance's definition of i
    >>> f.bar()
    Foo.i is 5
    self.i is 3
```

Answer (score 18):

I used to explain it with this example

```
# By TMOTTM

class Machine:

    # Class Variable counts how many machines have been created.
    # The value is the same for all objects of this class.
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):

        # Notice: no 'self'.
        Machine.counter += 1

        # Instance variable.
        # Different for every object of the class.
        self.id = Machine.counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    machine1 = Machine()
    machine2 = Machine()
    machine3 = Machine()

    #The value is different for all objects.
    print 'machine1.id', machine1.id
    print 'machine2.id', machine2.id
    print 'machine3.id', machine3.id

    #The value is the same for all objects.
    print 'machine1.counter', machine1.counter
    print 'machine2.counter', machine2.counter
    print 'machine3.counter', machine3.counter
```

The output then will by

```
machine1.id 1
machine2.id 2
machine3.id 3

machine1.counter 3
machine2.counter 3
machine3.counter 3
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just started learning Python and this confused me as well for some time. Trying to figure out how it all works in general I came up with this very simple piece of code:

```
# Create a class with a variable inside and an instance of that class
class One:
    color = 'green'

obj2 = One()


# Here we create a global variable(outside a class suite).
color = 'blue'         

# Create a second class and a local variable inside this class.       
class Two:             
    color = "red"

    # Define 3 methods. The only difference between them is the "color" part.
    def out(self):     
        print(self.color + '!')

    def out2(self):
        print(color + '!')

    def out3(self):
        print(obj2.color + '!')

# Create an object of the class One
obj = Two()
```

When we call `out()` we get:

```
>>> obj.out()

red!
```

When we call `out2()`:

```
>>> obj.out2()

blue!
```

When we call `out3()`:

```
>>> obj.out3()

green!
```

So, in the first method `self` specifies that Python should use the variable(attribute), that "belongs" to the class object we created, not a global one(outside the class). So it uses `color = "red"`. In the method Python implicitly substitutes `self` for the name of an object we created(`obj`). `self.color` means "I am getting `color="red"` from the `obj`"

In the second method there is no `self` to specify the object where the color should be taken from, so it gets the global one `color = 'blue'`.

In the third method instead of `self` we used `obj2` - a name of another object to get `color` from. It gets `color = 'green'`.