# Object Oriented example in Python

Tags: python

I know its dumb question but i am trying to grasp the concepts of OOP in Python. Suppose i want to write the program for factorial in **Procedural** form, i would do something like this

```
def factorial(n):
    num = 1
    while n >= 1:
        num = num * n
        n = n - 1
    return num

f = factorial(3)
print f # 6
```

Now i want to rewrite the same factorial program in OO way. i am not getting how to write this same function using objects and classes.

```
class Factorial():
    def fact(n):
        num = 1
        while n >= 1:
            num = num * n
            n = n - 1
        return num

f = Factorial()
a = f.fact(3)
print a # TypeError: fact() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I know this can be done more precisely in **Functional** way by using **lambdas** and other things, but i am learning the concepts of OOP. What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling an instance method, by default the current object is passed as the first parameter to the function. In your case,

```
def fact(n):
```

when you call it like this

```
a = f.fact(3)
```

it will be actually treated like this

```
a = fact(f, 3)
```

The reason why the current object is passed is, to let the instance method make changes to the object. (Remember Python doesn't have any other keyword like `this`, like in some other languages).

But your function's signature doesn't match this (it expects only one parameter). That's why it is throwing

```
# TypeError: fact() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

To fix this, you have to change the signature to something like this

```
def fact(self, n):
```

Now, the `self` parameter will receive the current object being passed.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `self` parameter:

```
class Factorial():
    def fact(self,n): #Forgot the self parameter huh?
        num = 1
        while n >= 1:
            num = num * n
            n = n - 1
        return num
```

I recommend you read these too:

- [explaining the self variable to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner)
- [Python 'self' explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)
- [Dive into Python - *defining Classes*](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html)

Comment: Ugh, i got it. This **self** thing is confusing.

Comment: Also might want to consider: class Factorial(Object):  It works without doing that though.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend these article for reading:

[An Introduction to Object-Oriented Concepts in Python, Part 1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2145968)

Unfortunately I cannot put more that 2 links But I'm sure you'll find other 4 parts of these.