# What is 'self' in the last parameter?

Tags: python

What does `self` in the last parameter what refer to? I tried to search about self in last parameter but no luck, so what I mean is something like this:

```
self.tilemap.update(dt, self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is the same thing as `self` anywhere else in the method. It is *just a reference to the current instance*.

`self` is just a naming convention; it is commonly used as the name for the first argument automatically passed to a method. Within the method, you can then use that name where ever you want to use the current instance; you can call methods on it, you can set attributes on it, *or* you can pass that reference on to other methods. See [Explaining the python 'self' variable to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner).

In this case, the current instance is being passed into another method as argument. There is nothing special about it being passed in as the last argument; it is *just another argument*.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is the current instance of a `class`. Please see:

- [Explaining the python 'self' variable to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner)
- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Comment: Thank you for much for the links, it helps me a a lot