# When I am trying to pass an image through pygame, it keeps saying 'pygame.Surface' has no attribute

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this, but I can't seem to find it. I know it is probably a simple fix, but I cannot find what is making this happen. This is the first part of my code :

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WINDOWWIDTH = 900
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
MOVERATE = 5
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 40
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 200
y = 150
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    super(player, self).__init__()

    temp_image = pygame.image.load("stand_down.png").convert_alpha()
    self.image_down = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

    temp_image = pygame.image.load("standleft.png").convert_alpha()
    self.image_left = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

    temp_image = pygame.image.load("standright.png").convert_alpha()
    self.image_right = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))

    self.image = self.image_down

    # keep position and size in pygame.Rect()
    # to use it in collision checking
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
def draw(self, x, y):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)            
def handle_event(self):#, event)
    self.image = self.image_down.get_rect()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((x, y))
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[K_LEFT]:
        self.rect.x -= 50
        self.image = self.image_left
    if key[K_RIGHT]:
        self.rect.x += 50
        self.image = self.image_right
class room1():
#bedroom
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 16, WINDOWHEIGHT/2
        self.speed = 3
    def draw(self):
        background = pygame.image.load("bedroom.jpg").convert()
        background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

And this is my main function :

```
def main():
     while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                player.handle_event.get(event)
            player.handle_event(screen)
    room1.draw(screen)
    player.draw(screen, x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
main()
```

I keep getting the same error :

```
File "C:\Python32\Project3\proj3pt2.py", line 220, in handle_event
self.image = self.image_down.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'image_down'
```

I know it's probably an easy fix, but I don't know where to look for it, and how I messed up. If someone could explain that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: again the same question. where do you create player ? Don't you do `player = player.transform.scale()` or something similar ?  It replace `Sprite` with `Surface` and you have problem. BTW: in line in error message `self.image = self.image_down.get_rect()` you replace `Surface` with `Rect` so you make similar mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an instance and call one of its methods, the instance gets automatically passed as the first argument, `self`. So if you have a class `MyClass` and an instance `my_instance` and you call its  `handle_event` method, it's the same as calling `MyClass.handle_event(my_instance)`.

In your program you never create an instance of the `player` class and so you're passing the `screen` as the `self` argument directly to the class (the `screen` is actually a `pygame.Surface`). That means the `self` in the `handle_event` method actually refers to the `screen` surface and since surfaces don't have an `image_down` attribute, Python raises an error when the  `self.image_down.get_rect()` part is reached.

To fix this problem, you have to create an instance (also called object) of the `player` class and must not pass an argument to `handle_event` (unless you add more parameters to the method):

```
player_instance = player(x_position, y_position)
```

Then use the instance inside of the while and event loops:

```
while True:
    player_instance.handle_event()
```

You also have to create an instance of the `room1` class instead of using the class directly.

Here's a complete example with some comments about other problems:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
WINDOWWIDTH = 900
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
FPS = 40
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Load images once globally and reuse them in the program.
background = pygame.image.load("bedroom.jpg").convert()
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
temp_image = pygame.image.load("stand_down.png").convert_alpha()
image_down = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))
temp_image = pygame.image.load("standleft.png").convert_alpha()
image_left = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))
temp_image = pygame.image.load("standright.png").convert_alpha()
image_right = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 200))


class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(player, self).__init__()

        self.image_down = image_down
        self.image_left = image_left
        self.image_right = image_right

        self.image = self.image_down

        # keep position and size in pygame.Rect()
        # to use it in collision checking
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

    # You don't have to pass x and y, since you already
    # use the `self.rect` as the blit position.
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self):
        # These two lines don't make sense.
        #self.image = self.image_down.get_rect()
        #self.image = pygame.Surface((x, y))
        # I guess you want to switch back to image_down.
        self.image = self.image_down

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 5
            self.image = self.image_left
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 5
            self.image = self.image_right

class room1():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 16, WINDOWHEIGHT/2
        # Reference to the background image.
        self.background = background

    def draw(self, screen):  # Pass the screen.
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))


def main():
    # Create player and room instances.
    player_instance = player(200, 150)
    room1_instance = room1()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Users can press the "X" button to quit.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        player_instance.handle_event()
        room1_instance.draw(screen)
        player_instance.draw(screen)
        # You don't need both update and flip.
        # pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

main()
pygame.quit()
```

---

Side note: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) recommends uppercase names for classes, so `Player` instead of `player`. Then you could call the instance `player`.

Comment: If it's unclear how `self` works, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990217/6220679).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you do somewhere something like this

```
 player = player.transform.scale(player.image)
```

`player` is `Sprite` but `scale` returns `Surface` - so you replace `Sprite` with `Surface` and later you have problems.

(BTW: I saw the same problem in some question few days ago)

If you have to rescale image then do it in `__init__` as you already do with some images.

In real game you should create images with correct sizes using any Image Editor so you don't have to use `scale()`

---

BTW: in `handle_event` you do

```
self.image = self.image_down.get_rect()
self.image = pygame.Surface((x, y))
```

You assign `Rect` to `Surface` (`self.image`) and later you assing new empty `Surface` with size `x, y`. `Surface` doesn't keep positon, it uses only `width, height`.

You have `self.rect` to keep positiona and you already change it with

```
self.rect.x -= 50
```

and

```
self.rect.x += 50
```

---

BTW: use `UpperCaseNames` for classes to make code more readable

```
class Player(...)

class Room1(...)
```

Event `Stackoverflow` knows this rule and it uses light blue color for classes to make code more readable.

More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

BTW: in `room1.draw()` you read and rescale image again and again - it can slow down program. Do it in `room.__init__`