# Finding depth of binary tree in Python

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a python code to find the depth of a binary tree. I have successfully implemented the C++ version but when I implement the same code in python it is giving a different answer in Leetcode. 
C++ version:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {

        if(!root) return 0;
        int l=maxDepth(root->left);
        int r=maxDepth(root->right);
        return 1 + max(l, r); 
    }
```

Python version:

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):

        if root is None:
                  return 0           
        self.left=self.maxDepth(root.left)     
        self.right=self.maxDepth(root.right)        
        return max(self.left,self.right) +1
```

Is there any fundamental difference in how recursive calls are made in Python and C++. My python code fails for the following case:[[1,2,3,4,5]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij5PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not identical. `self.left` means that you are modifying a field of `Solution` object in case of Python (cf. .[Explaining the python 'self' variable to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner/)). To use local variables forgo the use of `self` prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have used C++ most of my time and have just started using Python so I am little weak in the details of it. Really appreciate your help :)