# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' expecting multiple values

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cors

I was having issues with CORS for my server, and I tried to include the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". When I ran the code below, it expected another input argument, even though the documentation shows that it only needs 2.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socketserver
import socket
import http.server
import sys


Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Port = 8005
localHost = socket.gethostname()
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", Port), Handler)


Handler.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
Handler.end_headers()


httpd.handle_request()
request = httpd.recv(1000000)


httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I run this, I get the following issue:

```
 File "serverDP.py", line 29, in <module>
    Handler.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
TypeError: send_header() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

I've tried code from here and Github, but haven't had any luck.
Thanks for the help.

**Edit**

I added a class and it now looks like this:

```
class CORSRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def send_my_headers(self):
        print("This is working :/")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()

Handler = CORSRequestHandler
Handler.send_my_headers(Handler)
```

I still have the same issue. However I'm not exactly sure what I should pass into the "Handler.send_my_headers()" function

Comment: What is `Handler`? It isn’t defined anywhere in this code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I forgot to add that line in. Sorry

Comment: Is it a class? You probably need to create an instance before calling the method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner

Comment: ok I've added an edit to the main post including an instance before calling the method

Comment: That’s a subclass, not an instance. To create an instance, use `Handler()` (or `CORSRequestHandler()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socketserver
import socket
import http.server
import sys

class CORSRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def send_my_headers(self):
        print("This is working :/")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()

print('Server listening on port 8000...')
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', 8000), CORSRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```