# How to use add_reaction() without Type Error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Pokemon center command on request of a friend. The plan is to continue the dialogue whenever the user reacts with the 'A' emoji (:a:), so I'm trying to have the bot react to its own message first.
Here's the code

```
@bot.command()
async def joy(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(f'Welcome to our Pokémon Center!')
    emoji = bot.get_emoji(706288524089098360)
    await msg.add_reaction(msg,emoji)
```

Whenever I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: add_reaction() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explaining the 'self' variable to a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-self-variable-to-a-beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to put `msg` as parameter of `add_reaction()`, just use `msg.add_reaction(emoji)` with a unicode emoji. [Here is the doc for `add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message)

The `self` variable mustn't be specified, `add_reaction()` gets it form `msg` before the dot by himself in `msg.add_reaction(emoji)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge help! I'm sorry if I sound pushy but now I get 'InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType'. Any ideas?

Comment: The error message says that `emoji` variable is not a string and that you have to convert it

Comment: Verify type of `emoji` and `if(emoji != None)`