# Python method call from class to class

Tags: python, class, call

I'm learning Python and I'm getting confused with syntax for calls from one class to another. I did a lot of search, but couldn't make any answer to work. I always get variations like:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Help much appreciated

```
import random
class Position(object):
    '''
    Initializes a position
    '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

class RectangularRoom(object):
    '''
    Limits for valid positions
    '''
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def getRandomPosition(self):
        '''
        Return a random position
        inside the limits
        '''        
        rX = random.randrange(0, self.width)
        rY = random.randrange(0, self.height)

        pos = Position(self, rX, rY)
        # how do I instantiate Position with rX, rY?

room = RectangularRoom()
room.getRandomPosition()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `self` - that is the newly created instance, and is automatically given by Python.

```
pos = Position(rX, rY)
```

Note that the error here is happening on this line, however:

```
room = RectangularRoom()
```

The issue on this line is you are not giving `width` or `height`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. Still fightin´to understand classes!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answers to these previous questions help you understand why python decided to add that explicit special first parameter on methods:

- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)
- [Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method)
- [Python - why use "self" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475871/python-why-use-self-in-a-class)

The error message may be a little cryptic but once you have seen it once or twice you know what to check:

1. Did you forgot to define a self/cls first argument on the method?
2. Are you passing all the required method arguments? (first one doesn't count)

Those expecting/given numbers help a lot.