# Difference between Class variables and Instance variables

Tags: python, class, oop

I have already read many answers here on Stack Exchange like [Python - why use "self" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475871/python-why-use-self-in-a-class)
After reading these answers, I understand that instance variables are unique to each instance of the class while class variables are shared across all instances.

While playing around, I found that this code which gives the output `[1]`:

```
class A:
    x = []
    def add(self):
        self.x.append(1)

x = A()
y = A()
x.add()

print "Y's x: ", y.x
```

However, this code gives `10` as the output, when in my opinion it should be `11`:

```
class A:
    x = 10
    def add(self):
        self.x += 1

x = A()
y = A()
x.add()

print "Y's x: ", y.x
```

Why `A` class variable is not updated when I run `x.add()`? I am not very experienced in programming, so please excuse me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Class variables are *shadowed* by instance attribute. This means that when looking up an attribute, Python first looks in the instance, then in the class. Furthermore, setting a variable on an object (e.g. `self`) always creates an instance variable - it never changes the class variable.

This means that when, in your **second** example you do:

```
self.x += 1
```

which is (in this case, see footnote) equivalent to:

```
self.x = self.x + 1
```

what Python does is:

1. Look up `self.x`. At that point, `self` doesn't have the instance attribute `x`, so the class attribute `A.x` is found, with the value `10`.
2. The RHS is evaluated, giving the result `11`.
3. This result is assigned to a new instance attribute `x` of `self`.

So below that, when you look up `x.x`, you get this new instance attribute that was created in `add()`. When looking up `y.x`, you still get the class attribute. To change the class attribute, you'd have to use `A.x += 1` explicitly – the lookup only happens when reading the value of an attribute.

---

Your **first** example is a classical gotcha and the reason you shouldn't use class attributes as "default" values for instance attributes. When you call:

```
self.x.append(1)
```

there is no assignment to `self.x` taking place. (Changing the *contents* of a mutable object, like a `list`, is not the same as assignment.) Thus, no new instance attribute is added to `x` that would shadow it, and looking up `x.x` and `y.x` later on gives you the same list from the class attribute.

---

**Note:** In Python, `x += y` is not always equivalent to `x = x + y`. Python allows you to override the in-place operators separately from the normal ones for a type. This mostly makes sense for *mutable* objects, where the in-place version will directly change the contents *without* a reassignment of the LHS of the expression. However, *immutable* objects (such as numbers in your second example) do not override in-place operators. In that case, the statement does get evaluated as a regular addition and a reassignment, explaining the behaviour you see.

(I lifted the above from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4773111/41655), see there for more details.)

Comment: Actually, `x += ...` is not always equivalent to `x = x + ...`. You can observe that if you change the code with the list class variabel to use `self.x += [1]` instead of `self.x.append(1)`.

Comment: I'd quibble a bit about `x += y` being generally equivalent to `x = x + y`; `__iadd__` and `__add__` are different.

Comment: @DSM Hm. It seems to work for the purposes of this example, I'll poke at the docs to see if I can phrase it without that handwaving though. EDIT: Donezo.

Comment: What do you mean _you shouldn't use class attributes as "default" values for instance attributes ?_

Comment: @Mayank It's a somewhat dodgy pattern, where you use them to "initialize" an instance attribute instead of putting that code into `__init__()`. It works for immutable values but it's problematic if you end up sharing a mutable value between instances. It's basically what you're doing in your second example, if you intended the class variable `x` to really be a way to initialize `self.x`.