# Can a class variable be created inside one of the class' methods in Python?

Tags: python

Touching on the following question posted on SO, [Python - why use "self" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475871/python-why-use-self-in-a-class?rq=1), I was wondering:

If I created a variable inside a method of a given class without using the "self.", will it be a class variable? And if this is not the case, why not?

So for instance if I have a class like so:

```
class A:
    def somefunction(self):
        x=1
```

Will *x* be a class variable?

Comment: You ought to read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no. Because of x is not class variable - it is local variable of method `somefunction`.

[Class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) should be defined exactly in the class body:

```
class A:
    x = 1
    def somefunction(self):
        A.x += 1
        print A.x
```

**BTW:** even if you had defined classvariable correct, you would anyway got output:

```
2
2
```

because of in `somefunction` you're assigning `x=1`, so each time this function is run value of `x` is reset to `1` :)

Comment: I should actually rephrase my question to "can class variables be created in methods"

Comment: Possibly.., most likely yes. You actually shouldn't ask questions before searching it in Google.

Comment: No, of course I have searched it, but with the added information I got from your answer/comment, the question can be rephrased to be more succinct and meaningful.

Comment: You changes made my answer confusing :(

Comment: Oh sorry.. But I think your answer makes perfect sense, apart from the last few lines explaining my example, which i have deleted. As you have pointed out, the function gets called multiple times, so the variable is reset/recreated and I think there is another reason it wouldn't work, namely because _x_ is immutable, so it seems to me that it would be just confusing to have it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you assign a variable in a Python function, it's created in the innermost local namespace by default. You aren't referring to a variable in a different namespace (like the `A` class) unless you explicitly declare it. So in your code, you're creating `x` in a local namespace, which is specific to that function - not even specific to that instance of `A`, since you didn't declare it as `self.x`. I believe that is why you get `2,2` instead of `2,3`.

Answer (score 1):

No, your assumption is wrong. It is a local variable.